# Mac lost ability to commit to apache svn

Tags: svn

Couple week ago commit just stopped working for me. The svn server is on an apache box that has had some ssl issues which were recently fixed (if that makes a difference) but overnight one night I lost the ability to commit.

I can still update, checkout, etc. Just nothing that requires authentication.

Committing in eclipse on my Mac returns this.

```
Some of selected resources were not committed.
Authentication error.
svn: E170001: Commit failed (details follow):

svn: E170001: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E170001: MKACTIVITY of '/repos/!svn/act/472410fd-4d01-0010-a8b0-4523497c60f6': 403 Forbidden (https://xxx.xxxxxxx.com)
```

I thought it might be my credentials (based on similar posts) so I wiped them from ~/.subversion/auth/svn.simple

I figured without them it would ask for a user/pass.... and it didn't. I can't seem to get any svn client (via eclipse, sublime, tortoisesvn on my home windows machine) to ask me for them.

Any ideas welcome. If you need more information, I'm happy to provide it.

What's driving my nuts is that our team in India, on Windows boxes using tortoisesvn can still commit, even using my credentials.

It's crazy making.

Comment: Have you tried using `--username` and `--password` on the command line?

Comment: Yep. Just did a new checkout like this: "svn co --username myusername --password mypassword --trust-server-cert --non-interactive https:// xxx.xxxxx.com/repos/ ". It downloaded but when I made a change and tried to commit (in sublime), it gave me this. 
p
svn: E175013: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: E175013: MKACTIVITY of '/repos/!svn/act/4ee74291-4a4f-442c-87bf-f49993f40ad3': 403 Forbidden (https:// xxx.xxxxx.com)